# Trigger Sparkline inline graph after Ajax Success

Tags: jquery, mysql, ajax

I have the code below that is used to fetch data from a MYSQL database using Ajax.

My testing shows that I am receiving the result successfully.

The problem I a am having is to force sparkline to render the graphs after the call is successful.

If I am put the data directly in the page without the Ajax call, the graph is rendered without any issues, however it is not rendered if the data comes after the call ajax is successful.

From my investigation, I suspect the solution is to force sparkline to do a re-render after the ajax call. so How do I do this? 
Below is my ajax code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       var id = 1;
                    $.post("dashboardprocessor.php", {c1:id},function(data){
                    $("#c1").html(data);

                    });

    });
```

The page where the render is suppose to happen already has the sparkline.js file included.

Answer (score 0):

Your returned response 'data' has to be an array of values like this:

var data = [15, 4, 15, 22, 10, 13];

```
// then you need to pass this array to the element
$('#'your-element).sparkline(data, {
    type: "bar",
    tooltipSuffix: " widgets"
});
```

Customize the graph with the options of your choice.
I hope this makes sense for you. :)

NOTE: I also advise you to use an '$.ajax' call and not ($.post), $.ajax is more flexible about configuration and (but is my opinion) much easier to read and understand.